# How to add a css class to a selected Paragraph/Div?

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any option in ckeditor by adding a css class by selecting a paragraph?

My requirements are that I have lengthy text in the field with some paragraphs. One of paragraph I want to change the style through css. So for that I want an option in the ckeditor toolbar from where I can add a css class to a paragraph, not from source and editing the html.

Like currently there is an option for the "Normal (DIV)" in the Format dropdown. Can I add another option in this dropdown with "DIV with class test" and it will add a div with a test css class?

Answer (score 1):

Adding Styleset to ckeditor config. but it only add style attribute to div not class.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('CustomStyle', [
    { name : 'TxtDanger', element : ['p','div','h1'], styles : {'color' : 'red' } }
]);

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.stylesSet = 'CustomStyle';
};
```

Now you Can Get 'TxtDanger' style in your ckeditor style dropdown. But, 'CustomStyle' is replace your default ckeditor styles(Paragraph, Heading1,2..). so first add all default style into your 'CustomStyle'. [here](http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/styles/styles/default.js) list of default styles.